# Is regular expression in .net framework 4.8 cached anyway?

Tags: c#, regex

I am writing a fairly simple test myself to understand regular expression's performance in .net 4.8. Basically case 1 no-reuse and no-compile, case 2 reuse, case 3 reuse and compile.

```
        //w is a stopwatch, totalRun is 5000 or 1 million
        w.Restart();
        ////case one no reuse, no compile
        for (int i = 0; i <= totalRun; i++)
        {
            var testString = "JY23";
            Regex r2 = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$");
            if (r2.Match(testString).Success)
            {
                ///do something
            }
        }
        w.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("regular expression as now:" + w.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms");

        w.Restart();
        ////case 2 reuse but no compile
        Regex r = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$");
        for (int i = 0; i <= totalRun; i++)
        {
            var testString = "JY23";
            if (r.Match(testString).Success)
            {
                ///do something
            }
        }
        w.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("regular expression  reuse:" + w.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms");

        w.Restart();
        ////case 3 reuse and  compile
        Regex r1 = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$", RegexOptions.Compiled);
        for (int i = 0; i <= totalRun; i++)
        {
            var testString = "JY23";
            if (r1.Match(testString).Success)
            {
                ///do something
            }
        }
        w.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("regular expression  compiled:" + w.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms");
```

What I found is that for the three cases, the one run first always has the worst performance.

In this code, the no-reuse and no-recompile has the worst performance (ranges between 40-70ms) and other two has really good performance (1ms).

But if I run reuse, or compile cases first and then the no-reuse and no-compile cases, the first running one will have the worst performance (range between 40-60ms) and the no-reuse and no-compile one's performance range beteen 1ms to20ms.

I am bit surprised by what I see, does it mean .net framework actually cache regular expression anyway, so there isn't much need for me to use the compiled option or even reuse?

Comment: Some information about Regular Expression Compilation and Reuse - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/compilation-and-reuse-in-regular-expressions

Comment: I know this doc, but what this doc says does not match my tests

Comment: Perhaps you could add this as extra information to your question. You should also explain the differences between that documentation and your experience.

Comment: There may be a huge amount of JIT compilation the first time you run *any* Regex. So perhaps you need to do a different warmup Regex before you start, in order to test

Comment: https://benchmarkdotnet.org/ , accept no substitute.

Comment: I can't reproduce it, whatever I change the order, the case using new Regex is always about 10x slower.

Comment: are you using net 4.8 or different framework?

Comment: your benchmark is flawed. You need some warmup iterations and many other complex things to do a proper benchmark in a manage JIT environment like C# or Java. Please check on https://benchmarkdotnet.org